# Decomposition of UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Note that $R={\mathbb Z}$ is PID. So we have that if $I,\ J,\ K\subset R$ are ideals with $$ I = J\cap K$$ then $$(\ast)\ R/I = R/J\times R/K. $$

So we extend this. Let $R = {\mathbb Z}[x]$ which is UFD but not PID. Let $$ I= ((x^2+1)(x^3+1),2) = J\cap K,\ J =((x^2+1),2),\ K= ((x^3+1),2) $$

Then we have $(\ast)$ ? Right ?

Comment: This isn't correct as stated. If $I=J=K=(2)$, then you are saying that $F_2\cong F_2\times F_2$. You need $J$ and $K$ to be coprime to get the isomorphism you're using. The chinese remainder theorem holds for any ring with $J$ and $K$ coprime ideals, and doesn't have anything to do with being a PID or UFD.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that $x^2+1$ and $x^3+1$ are not coprime polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$. They have a common root (namely $1$).